# h5py - HDF5 database randomly returning NaNs and near very small data with multiple readers?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have an HDF5 dataset and I'm using a framework which is creating multiple processes to read from it (PyTorch's DataLoader, but this framework shouldn't be important). I'm indexing the first dimension of a 3D float array randomly, and to debug what was going on, I have been summing the slice from the indexing. Every once and a while, the summed slice turns out nan or as an extremely small value (a value that shouldn't appear in my data). If I preform the same index twice in a row, the values come out correct the other time (either the first or the second index might come out wrong). For example, below is some of values I get during indexing, where the left is expected to match the right, but sometimes the value comes out wrong:

```
21.2162 21.2162
89.9759 6.5469e-33
35.7114 35.7114
35.2934 35.2934
56.8512 56.8512
42.2215 42.2215
11.5307 nan
19.2904 19.2904
25.4261 25.4261
```

This comes from indexing one right after the other:

```
print(dataset[index].sum(), end=' ')
print(dataset[index].sum())
```

The problem does not seem to arise when I only use a single process to index the dataset. The dataset is only being read from (no writing). Does anyone know why this might be happening and if there's a way to prevent it?

Comment: "when I only use a single process to index the dataset" -> so you appear to use hdf5 in a multithreaded environment. This is not a standard situation and to go further, any potential help should know about the configuration used to write and to read the data: parallel library, method for opening the file and writing data in parallel, etc.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, it was my understanding that the parallel library is required only if I'm also writing to the database. Is that incorrect? Is the parallel library required even for just multiple readers with no writers?

Comment: No, but I wanted to make sure that you were not using multiple writers, as your post is not very descriptive. Are you using the SWMR feature? Is the file open for writing at the same time as for reading? What is your parallel setup?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, Sorry, I did specify "The dataset is only being read from (no writing)", but I suppose I could have made it more clear that I'm not writing. The dataset is not open for writing (by any process), only reading. The File object (from the h5py Python API) is opened for reading. This file handle (along with a callable for how to index it, which is just a simple indexing as above) is passed to PyTorch's Dataloader, which appears to use multiprocessing internally. So the file object should just have it's datasets being read with multiple Python processes.

Comment: Sorry for overlooking the "no writing" part. I don't know PyTorch and so cannot comment on its operation but what I know is that HDF5 is not threadsafe and so unsuitable for shared memory parallelism. The "torch-hdf5" library has [specific instructions](https://github.com/deepmind/torch-hdf5/blob/master/doc/usage.md#reading-hdf5-file-from-multiple-threads) for parallelism, emphasizing that special care must be taken. Your options: 1. have a single thread in charge of HDF5 operation. 2. Use torch-hdf5 following their instructions. 3. Maybe there are other solutions though.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the very same issue, and after spending a day trying to marry PyTorch DataParallel loader wrapper with HDF5 via h5py, I discovered that it is crucial to open `h5py.File` inside the new process, rather than having it opened in the main process and hope it gets inherited by the underlying multiprocessing implementation.

Since PyTorch seems to adopt lazy way of initializing workers, this means that the actual file opening has to happen inside of the `__getitem__` function of the `Dataset` wrapper.

Comment: I know this is from 2018 but I found this to not work for me, I am opening the file from within the getitem and still getting corrupted outputs.

Answer (score 6):

according to [this answer](https://gist.github.com/bkj/f448025fdef08c0609029489fa26ea2a#file-h5py-error-py), there is modified code, it can work well:

the modification is that we should close the object in h5py.File in `__len__` and `__getitem__` function.

the sample codes are here:

```
class DeephomographyDataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self,hdf5file,imgs_key='images',labels_key='labels',
         transform=None):

    self.hdf5file=hdf5file


    self.imgs_key=imgs_key
    self.labels_key=labels_key
    self.transform=transform
def __len__(self):

# return len(self.db[self.labels_key])
    with h5py.File(self.hdf5file, 'r') as db:
        lens=len(db[self.labels_key])
    return lens
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    with h5py.File(self.hdf5file,'r') as db:
        image=db[self.imgs_key][idx]
        label=db[self.labels_key][idx]
    sample={'images':image,'labels':label}
    if self.transform:
       sample=self.transform(sample)
    return sample
```